# SqlDataReader with SqlParameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to run a query that relies on parameters.

I've used it before and it works, but in this occasion there seems to be an issue, that I can't get my head around.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

This is the code I have:

```
 public void getMissingKeys()
 {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connection);

        conn.Open();

        foreach(DataRow dr in _result.Rows)
        {
            string sqlSearch = "SELECT TOP 1 [Column1], 
             [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], 
             [Column6], [Column7], [Column8] 
             FROM KeyValuationActual_destination 
             WHERE [SystemType] = @system 
             AND [DataType] = @data 
             AND [Location] LIKE @location 
             AND [Department] LIKE @department 
             AND [Role] LIKE @role 
             AND [Language] LIKE @language 
             AND [Shift] LIKE @shift
             AND [ResourceID] = @resource
             AND [Activity] LIKE @activity AND
             [Unique ID] IS NOT NULL";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSearch, conn);

            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[9];
            parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@system", SqlDbType.Float);
            parameters[0].Value = dr["SystemType"];

            parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Float);
            parameters[1].Value = dr["DataType"];

            parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@location", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[2].Value = dr["Location"].ToString();

            parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@department", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[3].Value = dr["Department"].ToString();

            parameters[4] = new SqlParameter("@role", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[4].Value = dr["Role"].ToString();

            parameters[5] = new SqlParameter("@language", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[5].Value = dr["Language"].ToString();

            parameters[6] = new SqlParameter("@shift", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[6].Value = dr["Shift"].ToString();

            parameters[7] = new SqlParameter("@resource", SqlDbType.Float);
            parameters[7].Value = dr["ResourceID"];

            parameters[8] = new SqlParameter("@activity", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
            parameters[8].Value = dr["Activity"].ToString();

            foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }


            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
}
```

Column1..8 are fictitious names.

Somehow I see that the parameters are actually being queried correctly and returned, but the `SqlDataReader` seems that can't handle the variables to "replace" them in the query command.

So the `reader.Read()` never returns any value.

I wonder if its the parameter types (I also tried to use nullables for the VarChars).

On debug if I check cmd and head to the "Non-Public members", I see two errors:

> EventSink = 'cmd.EventSink' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>
> InternalSmiConnection = 'cmd.InternalSmiConnection' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'

[Screeenshot from debug on cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYdS5.png)

I've been searching everywhere, but I'm clueless on how to proceed.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I eventually managed to make this work.

I've abandoned the ExecuteReader as this was not retrieving rows, even combined with a DataTable. It also seemed that if you want to use Parameters its stringly typed and since the table is using Float as type, this was giving me a headache to try to match the types.

I ended using and SqlAdapater, DataTable and parameters. It seems that the parameters are not that strongly typed as I don't need to do any casts.

So this is the code I ended up with:

```
public void getMissingKeys()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connection);
        string sqlSearch = "SELECT TOP 1 "+
                    "[Column1], [Column2], [Column3], "+
                    "[Column4], [Column5], [Column6], "+
                    "[Column7], [Column8] "+
                    "FROM KeyValuationActual_destination "+
                    "WHERE [SystemType] = @system "+
                    "AND [DataType] = @data "+
                    "AND [Location] LIKE @location "+
                    "AND [Department] LIKE @department "+
                    "AND [Role] LIKE @role "+
                    "AND [Language] LIKE @language "+
                    "AND [Shift] LIKE @shift "+
                    "AND [Resource Utilisation Ref_ID] = @resource "+
                    "AND [Activity] LIKE @activity "+
                    "AND [Unique ID] IS NOT NULL";

        try {
            foreach (DataRow dr in _result.Rows)
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSearch, conn);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", dr[2]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", dr[3]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", dr[4]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@language", dr[5]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shift", dr[7]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resource", dr[8]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activity", dr[9]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", dr[10]);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@system", dr[11]);

                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dataTable);

                if(dataTable != null)
                {
                    foreach(DataRow keyRow in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        dr[13] = keyRow["Column1"];
                        dr[14] = keyRow["Column2"];
                        dr[15] = keyRow["Column3"];
                        dr[16] = keyRow["Column4"];
                        dr[17] = keyRow["Column5"];
                        dr[18] = keyRow["Column6"];
                        dr[19] = keyRow["Column7"];
                        dr[20] = keyRow["Column8"];
                    }

                }
            conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Querying keys exception information! : {0}", ex);
        }
        
    }
```

I'm open to suggestions if you think something can be improved in this code

Comment: I noticed a few `like`s expressions, if you don't add the '%' whether in the parameter value or in the query, it won't treated as a like, do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: Strip out all of the parameters and run the query. Hopefully you'll get the first of many rows. Add parameters back one at a time until it "breaks"

Comment: Those exceptions are irrelevant, that's just the debugger trying its best to access all the data it possibly can. You almost always see a few exceptions like that, it doesn't mean they are necessarily problems. I agree with kblok, `LIKE`s are treated as `=` if you don't use a wildcard character.

Comment: AFAIK, both `EventSink` & `InternalSmiConnection` are non-public members, they're not commonly used for regular connections. Check if the `SqlDataReader` has results using `HasRows` before iterating the content.

Comment: @kblok/Crowcoder: I also tried to use = instead of `like` but the result was the same.
@n8wrl - I'll try that.

Comment: Which line if code is throwing exception?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya: `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

Comment: The data coming from datarows are of the same type as parameters? Tried converting values to float for respective parameters?

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto: I have added that and it does not return any rows.
I also used `LIKE` (`... FROM KeyValuationActual_destination WHERE [SystemType] LIKE '%' + @system + '%'"`) to check for this value as I see that Float has raised a lot of questions, and I can't change that from the table. I also casted the parameter value as Float and Double but still no results. I'm just using `SystemType` column to keep things simple until I get this right.

Comment: Minor detial, but if you're using `TOP 1` in the query, you don't need to loop on the results since you'll only ever have one.

Comment: @LeonelSerra `SqlDataReader` itself known to be having issues, due to its behavior which iterates data only in forward manner. Since the query works on SSMS, you may transfer result of `ExecuteReader` results to a `DataSet` or `DataTable` and iterate stored data from those instances, or build `WHERE` clause with proper usage of `LIKE` operator.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, how is forward-only an issue? I've never heard of problems with SqlDataReader.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto after testing and tweaking other ways with `ExecuteReader`, I saw that this might not result in what I want from other StackOverflow questions, as it seems it has a particular way for this to work... maybe even with the type of data or query you want to do. I eventually managed to make this work with your suggestion and used a `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataTable` and parameters. It seems these are not so strongly typed, so I don't need to cast. I'll write my solution and you guys can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Are your SqlDbType enums all correct? Are 'System Type', 'Data Type' and 'ResourceID' actually floats?

Comment: Yes. I'm basing these on the actual database design.

Answer (score 0):

No compile or run-time errors with an empty `DataReader` tells me it's an issue with your `WHERE` clause. Here are some places you might prod:

1. [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) without the wildcard (`%`) is the same as `=` in SQL. `LIKE` is equivalent to "equals|starts-with|ends-with|contains", depending on where you put the wildcard[s]. To search the whole field ("contains"), you would do something like this:
   `parameters[8].Value = string.Format("%{0}%", dr["Activity"].ToString());`
2. The way your `WHERE` clause is structured, you must have a perfect match on all fields, and no parameters can be null or empty. You're going to need to handle blank/null input values for cases in which not all parameters are utilized. Not sure if this is a use case, but it's a common gotcha. Use grouped logic like this:

   ```
   AND ([Department] LIKE @department 
      OR @department IS NULL 
      OR @department  = '')
   AND (AND [Role] LIKE @role 
      OR @role IS NULL 
      OR @role = '')
   ```
3. Why not filter on the `UniqueID` field? You're only checking if it's null. This seems like a primary key. Filtering on primary keys is good practice when possible.
4. As also suggested by [@n8wrl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37710/n8wrl), try running the query with no WHERE clause and no parameters. You should get a result, if not, your problem isn't SQL. Add fields back in and test until you stop getting a result. A lot of problem solving boils down to breaking problems down into bite-sized chunks.

---

On a semi-related note, I have a code-style and SO-meta suggestion: line width limits. Set a soft limit between, say, 50-100 characters everywhere you write code. I was here before the edit, and your long string literal on a single line created extra work in trying to analyze your problem. Which would you rather see when you revisit this code in year or two?

```
//Better one...
string sqlSearch = "SELECT TOP 1 [Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4], [Column5], [Column6], [Column7], [Column8] FROM KeyValuationActual_destination WHERE [SystemType] = @system AND [DataType] = @data AND [Location] LIKE @location AND [Department] LIKE @department AND [Role] LIKE @role AND [Language] LIKE @language AND [Shift] LIKE @shift AND [ResourceID] = @resource AND [Activity] LIKE @activity AND [Unique ID] IS NOT NULL";

//...or two?
string sqlSearch = 
  "SELECT TOP 1 " + 
     "[Column1], [Column2], [Column3], " + 
     "[Column4], [Column5], [Column6], " + 
     "[Column7], [Column8] " + 
  "FROM KeyValuationActual_destination " + 
  "WHERE [SystemType] = @system " + 
     "AND [DataType] = @data " + 
     "AND [Location] LIKE @location " + 
     "AND [Department] LIKE @department " + 
     "AND [Role] LIKE @role " + 
     "AND [Language] LIKE @language " + 
     "AND [Shift] LIKE @shift " + 
     "AND [ResourceID] = @resource " + 
     "AND [Activity] LIKE @activity " + 
     "AND [Unique ID] IS NOT NULL";
```

A "prettier" alternative is the [C# verbatim string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) (see string j in the example). I usually prefer the first method because it is explicit about whitespace, but it's up to you.

Comment: Hey... great suggestions CaptainMarvel. I actually see where you going. Not to try to blame others, but this is how this table is structured and I'm trying to "guess" some values based on previous entries and for that I need to match a few values in a single row in order to look for it in previous rows. That is no problem, since I'm just testing this and I know which matches I should get. I there are no matches these are returned so that I can have a look at them. I guess this takes care of points 1,2 & 3

Comment: I also tried to run the query in the server directly and it works, but it seems that involving SqlReader does not work with this code

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to dispose, and for convenience sake, I would also encourage a preference for the multi-line string literal instead of the normal string. That will make it much easier to edit/copy/paste/etc down the road.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var sql = @"
  SELECT TOP 1
  FROM KeyValuationActual_destination
  WHERE [SystemType] = @system
  ";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connection))
{
  conn.Open();
  using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
  {
    // blah blah blah
    da.Fill(dataTable);
  }
}
// "using" statements avoid the need to manually Close(), Dispose(), etc.
```